nth-of-type from 4 to 7 only
I am trying to create a hover:before and a hover:after for my menu navbar. The menu contain 7 items:
menu 1, menu 2, menu 3 (these will use hover:before)
logo in the middle (in place of menu 4)
menu 5, menu 6, menu 7 (these will use hover:after)
I can select the menu from 1 to 3 like this:
menu:hover:nth-of-type(-n+3)::before {background:red}

But how do I select from 5 to 7 ?
I am trying like this:
menu:hover:nth-of-type(5+-n)::after {background:green}

Also tried (5,6,7), (5-7) but I cannot understand how this is done.
I tried looking for answers from previous questions here but cannot find an answer for this specific case.
Any idea?
EDIT:
Here is the HTML
<nav role="navigation">
<menu><a href="#">1</a></menu>
<menu><a href="#">2</a></menu>
<menu><a href="#">3</a></menu>
<menu>
<logo><img src="logo.png"></logo>
<slogan>slogan here</slogan>
</menu>
<menu><a href="#">5</a></menu>
<menu><a href="#">6</a></menu>
<menu><a href="#">7</a></menu>
</nav>


I added the HTML now

MDN have very thorough examples which also covers your use case. Use :nth-of-type(n+5):nth-child(-n+7)  or just :nth-of-type(n+5).

Instead of using :nth-of-type you also could put a class on the menu with the logo (e.g. logo) and select the following items with the "subsequent siblings" selector: .logo ~ menu: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Subsequent-sibling_combinator

For 5 through 7, use :nth-of-type(n+5). The pattern is always An+B, where n starts at 0. So this selects elements 5, 6, 7, ...
See the explanation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child#functional_notation
Example


menu:hover:nth-of-type(-n+3) {
  background: red;
}
menu:hover:nth-of-type(n+5) {
  background: green;
}
<nav role="navigation">
  <menu><a href="#">1</a></menu>
  <menu><a href="#">2</a></menu>
  <menu><a href="#">3</a></menu>
  <menu>
    <logo><img src="logo.png"></logo>
    <slogan>slogan here</slogan>
  </menu>
  <menu><a href="#">5</a></menu>
  <menu><a href="#">6</a></menu>
  <menu><a href="#">7</a></menu>
</nav>




Wow it works, I still don't understand how it works but it is working :) Thank you very much. I will read some more about this because nth is a very interesting tool

As your 5-7 items are the last once you can use the 'nth-last-of-type' selector combined with 'n' as follows:
.menu:hover:nth-last-of-type(-n+3)::after { 
  background: green; 
}

Additionally do not forget to add styles for the ::before ad ::after pseudo-elements, so the full CSS will look as follows:
  .menu {
    position: relative;
  }
  .menu::before {
    content: "";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    inset: 0px;
  }
  .menu::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    inset: 0px;
  }
  .menu:hover:nth-of-type(-n+3)::before { 
    background: red; 
  }
  .menu:hover:nth-last-of-type(-n+3)::after { 
    background: green; 
  }


To select the menu elements from the 5th to the 7th position in the nav you can use:
1:
nav > menu:nth-child(n+5):not(:nth-child(-n+3)) a {
  /* styles for text inside menus 5 to 7 */
}

2:
nav > menu:nth-child(4) ~ menu:nth-child(n+1) {
  /* styles for menus 5 to 7 */
}

3:
nav menu:nth-of-type(n+5):nth-of-type(-n+7) {
  /* Your styles for menus 5 to 7*/
}

